# ScreenToWorldPoint does something strange in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to convert from screen coordinates to world coordinates in Unity, but failing.

I regarded third coordinate as a distance from camera [according to documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) and tried

```
 GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
 GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(100, 0, 0))
 GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 100, 0))
 GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(10000000, 0, 0))
 GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 10000000, 0))
```

But result was always

```
 (0.0, 0.0, 2.0)
```

where `(0.0, 0.0, 2.0)` is the coordinates of the camera object.

---

I found, that if third coordinate is zero, then first two coordinates has no effect. And if third coordinate is `1` then effect exists, but is different, than when third coordinate is `2`.

Is this by design?

Comment: That last line isn't valid code.

Comment: It's debugger output

Comment: As you correctly noted it is the distance from the camera. A value of 0 equates to the projection singularity of the camera, i.e. its origin. Here the "projection plane" collapses to a single point, so changing the screen coordinate has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in defining the variables.

Change this:

```
float mouseX = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
```

for this:

```
float mouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;
float mouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;
```

You're trying to get the mouse axis, but actually you need to get the mouse positions.

Comment: No, this is something other, I tried hardcoding, so the way how I obtain mouse coordinates doesn't matter.

Comment: Did you try this? The axis is like an speed of the mouse, and the mousePosition is the real position in pixels. I tested in my Unity, it makes a object follow the mouse in the Scene, no matter whats distance it have from camera. Try to delete the Mathf.Abs part and try thiscode , it worked for me.

Comment: It's a helpful note about meaning of speed / position, but not related with coordinates conversion....